# Why does hashing the same vector twice get different hash codes?

Tags: vector, hash, rust

I want to get the hash code of this vector:

```
let vec = vec![1,2,3];
let tmp = vec![1,2,3];
let mut hash = DefaultHasher::new();
vec.hash(&mut hash);
println!("{}", hash.finish());
tmp.hash(&mut hash);
println!("{}", hash.finish());
```

However the output is:

```
13585085576907263210
8618793686565720431
```

What's going on? I have tried multiple times and always get the same result. I want the vector with the same elements to hash to the same hash code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The hasher is not reset after `finish`. Create a new hasher state with `DefaultHasher::new()` for each hash value you want to compute.

Comment: Do you know how to avoid unnecessary malloc?